# SQL: return 0 count in case no record is found

Tags: sql, oracle

A very simple issue as it appears but somehow not working for me on Oracle 10gXE.

Based on [my SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90ba0/1), I have to show all staff names and count if present or 0 if no record found having status = 2

How can I achieve it in a single query without calling Loop in my application side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT S.NAME,ISTATUS.STATUS,COUNT(ISTATUS.Q_ID) as TOTAL
FROM STAFF S
LEFT OUTER JOIN  QUESTION_STATUS ISTATUS
ON S.ID = ISTATUS.DONE_BY
AND ISTATUS.STATUS = 2 <--- instead of WHERE
GROUP BY S.NAME,ISTATUS.STATUS
```

By filtering in the `WHERE` clause, you filter too late, and you remove `STAFF` rows that you do want to see. Moving the filter into the join condition means only `QUESTION_STATUS` rows get filtered out.

Note that `STATUS` is not really a useful column here, since you won't ever get any result other than `2` or `NULL`, so you could omit it:

```
SELECT S.NAME,COUNT(ISTATUS.Q_ID) as TOTAL
FROM STAFF S
LEFT OUTER JOIN  QUESTION_STATUS ISTATUS
ON S.ID = ISTATUS.DONE_BY
AND ISTATUS.STATUS = 2
GROUP BY S.NAME
```

Comment: Though all answered correctly, laughing at myself how I made a silly mistake by using WHERE clause. The reason to pick you that you also explained why you did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I corrected your sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90ba0/12

The rule of thumb is that the filters must appear in the ON condition of the table they depend on.

Answer (score 1):

Move filter into the LEFT JOIN , also use COALESCE to have your results display 0 instead of null as you requested in your question

```
select S.NAME,COALESCE(ISTATUS.STATUS,0),COUNT(ISTATUS.Q_ID) as TOTAL
from   STAFF S
LEFT  OUTER JOIN  QUESTION_STATUS ISTATUS
ON S.ID = ISTATUS.DONE_BY
AND  ISTATUS.STATUS =2
GROUP BY S.NAME,ISTATUS.STATUS
```

Comment: Huh, interesting interpretation of the question. I read it as `TOTAL` should be `0`, not `STATUS`, but indeed, if `STATUS` should be too, `COALESCE` would be the way to go.